# classical dynamics finding cartesianfunctions of spherical parameterization

Tags: calculus

I'm given the typical spherical parameterization where

$$x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi\\y=r\sin\theta \sin\phi\\z=r\cos\theta $$

I am to find $r(y,z,x),\theta(x,y,z)$ and $\phi(x,y,z)$. How exactly should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

> $r$

Note that

\begin{eqnarray}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &=& r^2\sin^2\theta \cos^2\phi + r^2\sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi + r^2\cos^2\theta \\
&=& r^2\sin^2\theta \cancelto{1}{(\cos^2\phi + \cos^2\phi)} + r^2\cos^2\theta \\
&=& r^2(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) = r^2
\end{eqnarray}

So $r(x, y, z) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

> $\phi$

Consider

$$
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{\cancel{r\sin\theta}\sin\phi}{\cancel{r\sin\theta}\cos\phi} = \tan{\phi}
$$

and then $\phi(x, y, z) = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$

> $\theta$

I will leave this one to you